# Chrome and Firefox return different error when click cancel button on browsers popup during FIDO2 credentai get

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, webauthn, fido

When I click cancel on dialog

Chrome returns NotAllowedError, But Firefox returns AbortError

[image]

In [W3C Webauthn document](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn/#discover-from-external-source), It says following thing

> 18.
>   While lifetimeTimer has not expired, perform the following actions
>   depending upon lifetimeTimer, and the state and response for each
>   authenticator in authenticators:
>
> -> If lifetimeTimer expires, For each authenticator in issuedRequests
>   invoke the authenticatorCancel operation on authenticator and remove
>   authenticator from issuedRequests.
>
> -> If the user exercises a user agent user-interface option to cancel the
>   process, For each authenticator in issuedRequests invoke the
>   authenticatorCancel operation on authenticator and remove
>   authenticator from issuedRequests. Return a DOMException whose name is
>   "NotAllowedError".
>
> -> If the signal member is present and the aborted flag is set to true,
>   For each authenticator in issuedRequests invoke the
>   authenticatorCancel operation on authenticator and remove
>   authenticator from issuedRequests. Then return a DOMException whose
>   name is "AbortError" and terminate this algorithm.
>   ...

I thought cancel returns NotAllowedError always.

Is it bug of Firefox browser ? or just I missed something ?

I gave following params to `navigator.credentials` as options

- challenge
- allow credentials
- user verification required / preferred